# How smashing magazine load images on first then content

Tags: jquery, html, css, loading, lazy-loading

If you see loading www.smashingmagazine.com its does load embeded image and background image on first then loads content..

how its doing that using lazy load concept..

Thanks ad regards

Comment: Use the source, Luke!

Answer (score 1):

It would suffice to load all the non-image content hidden, and then show it in body onload (rather than on DOMReady, as onload does not fire until images have loaded).

Answer (score -1):

No lazy loader is used when you load images or data when you scroll so these are image pre loading function is used.